# How to add a sample vertical line to in a gplot?

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2, normal-distribution, gplots

Consider the graph below given by this code:

```
require(ggplot2)
my_data<-c(70,  71, 75, 78, 78, 79, 80, 81, 84, 85, 87, 87, 90, 91, 95, 95, 96, 96, 97, 98, 98, 100,    101,    102,    102,    102,    102,    104,    104,    104,    107,    107,    109,    110,    110,    110,    111,    112,    113,    113,    114,    115,    118,    118,    118,    120,    124,    131,    137,    137,    139,    145,    158,    160,    162,    165,    169,    177,    179,    180)    


qplot(my_data,dist, geom="line")+xlab("x values")+ylab("Density")+
geom_point()+
ggtitle("cool graph Distribution") + 
geom_line(color="black", size=0.1) +
geom_line(stat = "vline", xintercept = "mean", colour = "red", size=1.1)
```

the resulted graph looks like this: 
[image]

My objective is to add another blue line to the graph that:

1. Intersect with the curve
2. Show the value on the X axis
3. Add a title on top of it

to visualize it, it should look like this:
[image]

**I know how to add a geom_line but it goes bottom-up, I wish for 'one point intersection' with the curve.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding vertical line in plot ggplot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622063/adding-vertical-line-in-plot-ggplot)

Comment: Disagree about the duplicate: those answers use `geom_vline` which wouldn't work for this question. (OP wants a line that only goes from y = 0 to the distribution line, not all the way to the top of the graph.) There probably are other duplicates, but the one linked above isn't a good match.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's really more or less the same. I prefer to use `annotate` for things like this. (I'd do your red line with annotate as well, personally.) Just calculate where you want things to go and add them to the plot:

```
qplot(my_data,dist, geom="line")+xlab("x values")+ylab("Density")+
    geom_point()+
    ggtitle("cool graph Distribution") + 
    geom_line(color="black", size=0.1) +
    geom_line(stat = "vline", xintercept = "mean", colour = "red", size=1.1) +
    annotate(geom = "segment", x = 98, xend = 98, y = 0,
             yend = dnorm(98, mean = mean(my_data), sd = sd(my_data)),
             color = "blue") +
    annotate(geom = "text", x = 98, y = -.02 * max(dist), label = "98")
```

I'll leave the title at the top as an "exercise for the reader", it should be pretty straightforward based on the pieces that are there already.