# Labeling specific points on the graph

Tags: r, graph, line, tidyverse

I have a line graph with data by month. My data frame looks like this:

```
x <- c("2013-01", "2013-02", "2013-03", "2013-04", "2013-05", "2013-06", "2013-07", "2013-08", "2013-09", "2013-10", "2013-11", "2013-12",
       "2014-01", "2014-02", "2014-03", "2014-04", "2014-05", "2014-06", "2014-07", "2014-08", "2014-09", "2014-10", "2014-11", "2014-12",
       "2015-01", "2015-02", "2015-03", "2015-04", "2015-05", "2015-06", "2015-07", "2015-08", "2015-09", "2015-10", "2015-11", "2015-12",
       "2016-01", "2016-02", "2016-03", "2016-04", "2016-05", "2016-06", "2016-07", "2016-08", "2016-09", "2016-10", "2016-11", "2016-12")

Articles <- c(0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 9, 6, 1, 0, 0, 1,
                3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 7, 106, 19, 16, 57, 115,
                26, 20, 33, 52, 45, 36, 32, 23, 21, 38, 17, 18,   
                6, 10, 14, 6, 17, 5, 34, 6, 11, 11, 2, 2)

PoliceFrame <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0,
              0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 29, 9, 2, 17, 46,
              13, 9, 14, 10, 13, 18, 6, 8, 7, 12, 1, 6,
              1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 7, 2, 1)

ProtesterFrame <- c(0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1,
                 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 6, 51, 6, 11, 18, 38,
                 8, 9, 11, 32, 22, 10, 15, 10, 10, 19, 9, 5,
                 3, 6, 6, 2, 8, 3, 8, 3, 8, 4, 0, 1)
```

I use the following code to create the graph:

```
data %>% 
  gather(subject, value, -x) %>% 
  mutate(x = as.Date(paste(x,"-01",sep="")))  %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x, y=value,
             group=subject, color = subject, shape = subject)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title="Media Attention",x="", y = "Media Articles")+
  geom_vline(xintercept=19, linetype = "longdash") +
  geom_vline(xintercept=6, linetype = "longdash") +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c(1,2,3)) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face="bold"), 
        legend.position = "bottom", legend.title = element_blank())
```

This produces the following plot:

[image: Plot]

There are two things I am trying to add to this plot:

(1) I want to add two vertical dashed lines at July 2013 and August 2014.

(2) I want to add labels only to where the red (Articles) peaks are. For example, there is a large spike at August 2014. I want to label that either on the x-axis or in the plot itself (where the red dot is). So basically I would labels at August 2014; December 2014; April 2015; October 2015; and July 2016.

Any guidance on how to accomplish either of these tasks will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: check with `geom_text` as showed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15015356/how-to-do-selective-labeling-with-ggplot-geom-point) and `geom_vline` for vertical lines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622063/adding-vertical-line-in-plot-ggplot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is done with `geom_vline`, the second with `geom_text`:

```
# separate the data manipulation from the plots so we can reuse it
data <- data %>%
  gather(subject, value, -x) %>% 
  mutate(x = as.Date(paste(x,"-01",sep="")))  

# your original plot call
p <- data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x, y=value,
    group=subject, color = subject, shape = subject)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title="Media Attention",x="", y = "Media Articles")+
  geom_vline(xintercept=19, linetype = "longdash") +
  geom_vline(xintercept=6, linetype = "longdash") +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c(1,2,3)) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face="bold"), 
    legend.position = "bottom", legend.title = element_blank())

# the new stuff:
p + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = as.Date(c("2013-07-01", "2014-08-01")), linetype = "dashed") + 
  geom_text(data = data[data$subject == 'Articles' & data$value > 60,], mapping = aes(label = x), hjust = 1, nudge_x = -10)
```

feel free to play with the values of `hjust` (0 = left-aligned, 1 = right-aligned, 0.5 = center) and `nudge_x`.  They can also be vectors if you want to apply different values to each label.

Comment: Thanks, Melissa! The text labels come out great. I have two issues that I'm still running into though. The vertical lines don't show up - I get the following error: "Error in Ops.Date((x - from[1]), diff(from)) : 
  / not defined for "Date" objects" . Also, I am hoping to label a few more spikes as well. All of the spikes are greater than 30 articles. The problem is there are other points that are over 30 that I do not want to label. Is there any way to label only a few specific points?

Comment: On the first issue - make sure you're using the most current version of `ggplot2`.  If that doesn't help, you may need to install the version from github.  On the second, set up the filter however you like.  I used `data$subject == 'Articles' & data$value > 60`, but you can use whatever criteria you like.