# Trying to find correlation between events and covid positivity rates

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-analysis, reproducible-research

I'm looking to test for correlation between specific events (mostly holidays) and a university's covid positivity rates. I've been using ggplot2 but am not sure of how I should look at the actual correlation values between the data, and how I could overlay the events onto the plot as markers on the plot.

Comment: Welcome on SO! For questions unrelated to programming and more about methods  ask on: https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Time-series ordinary least squares regression is an option

Comment: Maybe use vertical lines for your markers? This post shows how: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622063/adding-vertical-line-in-plot-ggplot